# How to loop through every div and check if contains certain element?

Tags: javascript

I'm building drag and drop puzzle game and I want to know how to check if all my droppable divs contains dragged images.

I want to put an `if` statement, something like:

```
if (all of my "box2" divs are filled with draggable "images") { 
  alert('Everything is cool')
} else {
  alert('Not cool')
}
```

My code so far:

```js
var dropTarget = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
let imgId = [];
let targetId = [];

for (let i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
  draggables[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function (ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("srcId", ev.target.id);
  });
}

dropTarget.addEventListener('dragover', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  imgId = ev.target.id.split("_");
});

dropTarget.addEventListener('drop', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let target = ev.target;
  let droppable = target.classList.contains('box2');
  let srcId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("srcId");
  targetId = ev.target.id.split("_");

  if (droppable) {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(srcId));
  }

  if (targetId[1] != srcId.split("_")[1]) {
    document.getElementById("text").style.border = "thick solid red";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="float:left;" id="box">
    <img class="task" id="img_1" src="img/puzz1.jpg" alt="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="task" id="img_2" src="img/puzz2.jpg" alt="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="task" id="img_3" src="img/puzz3.jpg" alt="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="task" id="img_4" src="img/puzz4.jpg" alt="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  </div>

  <div class="box2" style="float: right" id="text">
    <div id="drop_1" class="box2"></div>
    <div id="drop_2" class="box2"></div>
    <div id="drop_3" class="box2"></div>
    <div id="drop_4" class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your above example so it works and added alerts after every drop that say whether or not all the dropzones have been filled with images. The logic for the latter is all contained within the `areAllDropsFilled` function. Snippet:

```js
var dropTarget = document.querySelector("#drops");
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
let imgId = [];
let targetId = [];

for (let i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
  draggables[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function (ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("srcId", ev.target.id);
  });
}

dropTarget.addEventListener('dragover', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  imgId = ev.target.id.split("_");
});

dropTarget.addEventListener('drop', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let target = ev.target;
  let droppable = target.classList.contains('box2');
  let srcId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("srcId");
  targetId = ev.target.id.split("_");

  if (droppable) {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(srcId));
  }
 
  if (targetId[1] != srcId.split("_")[1]) {
    document.getElementById("drops").style.border = "thick solid red";
  }
 
 if(areAllDropsFilled()) {
  alert('you finished!');
 } else {
  alert('not yet done');
 }
});

function areAllDropsFilled() {
 return [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.box2')).every(box => box.childNodes.length > 0);
}
```

```css
#drops {
 display: inline-block;
}

.box2 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="tasks">
      <img class="task" id="img_1" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?1" draggable="true">
      <img class="task" id="img_2" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?2" draggable="true">
      <img class="task" id="img_3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?3" draggable="true">
</div>

<div id="drops">
  <div id="drop_1" class="box2"></div>
  <div id="drop_2" class="box2"></div>
  <div id="drop_3" class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will do the job, very elegant solution! I think I can continue from here alone :D Thanks a lot!